# How to select the top third row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Guys am trying to select the top/recently third row, i tried this one but it doesn't work, where do i make mistake ?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1,2;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['artist'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OFFSET:

```
SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

The shorthand (which you are using) is reversed, so OFFSET is first then LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2,1;
```

Comment: If there are multiple record with same data then it will not give all....it's not a correct answer

Comment: The question asked for the 3rd row. This gives that.

Answer (score 1):

Use OFFSET

Here the limit 1 It simply means and you need one record 
and the offset means skip the first 2

```
SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you use after limit should be reversed. 
The first parameter is offset, and the second parameter is number of record you want.

```
SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion--
Sorting like this should always be done in client software.
Extract the data - remove the ORDER BY for your SQL...
Sort it in your client, and select and return the third line to the caller.

You will get better scalability and maintainability than driving all of this through an SQL query.

This is my go-to approach when solving these types of problems through custom software and it has been proven out over time.

Think about this:
Select ID from songs

get the id's into your code, and sort them there. Then chose the third one in the list. Then:

select title, author, artist, ... from songs where ID = VALUE FROM ID ABOVE

Yes, you are hitting the database twice, but these are two very efficient queries and that will perform better as your database scales, than the fancy order by you propose.